# Null to empty string in Yii2

Tags: string, null, yii2

I have a problem that Yii2 model tries to save empty value as null, not as empty string. As far as I have not null mysql column, I am getting mysql error. In Yii 1 there was a config option 'nullConversion' => PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING . How can I achieve the same in Yii2? Just want ORM to save empty values as '', not null. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yii2 doesn't convert `null` to an empty string by default. If you **don't want** it to automatically convert a null to an empty string then:

- Check your code and make sure that field contains a `null` before calling the `save` method.
- `beforeSave` shouldn't replace fields.
- `PDO::NULL_TO_STRING` should not be set.

Also see [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/2869) issue.

If you **want** to automatically convert a null to an empty string then set `PDO::NULL_TO_STRING` in 'db' component.

```
    'db' => [
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=database',
        'attributes' => [
            PDO::NULL_TO_STRING => true
        ]
    ],
```

Comment: So, how can I make it to automatically convert null to empty string?

Comment: You can extends all your ActiveRecord from class where in beforeSave will be replace all null values to empty strings.

Comment: Yes, did that. So pitty no other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a different approach to solve this, using rules:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        ...
        [['field1', 'field2'], 'default', 'value' => ''],
        ...
```

This way you can have some fields default to empty strings instead of null, without affecting all fields.

Comment: Yes, but doing that website-wide would be a better approach.

Comment: That actually depends, specially if you actually need some fields to default to null.

Answer (score 2):

In order to automatically convert the mysql NULL to empty strings in Yii2, use this -

```
'db' => [
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=database',
    'attributes' => [
        PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => PDO::NULL_TO_STRING
    ]
],
```

Comment: Dunno how it works, but it does...not the accepted one. +1.